# What is wrong with this cast?

Tags: c++

I've been told that the following is bad code because z_strings is already a char array. However I don't really know much C++ so I don't really know what the usage is doing or why it would be wrong. Can somebody offer an explanation?

Declaration: `char z_strings[3];`

Usage: `MyFunction(myints, (char**)&z_strings, another_int_arg);`

Definition of MyFunction: `void MyFunction(int* my_ints, char** z_strings, int another_int_arg)`

For context, this is a coworker's "code review" code which is intentionally broken; he was using it to ask interview candidates to fix the bad code. However this coworker has actually left the company and the only notes say that it's a bad cast, and I'm trying to figure out some more details about why because I'm curious.

I removed context I thought was irrelevant, but for the full context MyFunction is actually `GetPowers(p_int, (char**)&z_strings, 3);` `p_int` will be an array like `[2,3,4]` and `z_strings` will be populated with values like `['Hundreds','Thousands','Ten Thousands']`, in other words this function translates numerical powers into English equivalents.

Comment: What's the definition of `MyFunction`?

Comment: why do you need to cast, actually?

Comment: Updated the question to include the definition for MyFunction.

Comment: As for why I need to cast, I'm not quite sure. For context, this is a coworker's "code review" code which is intentionally broken; he was using it to ask interview candidates to fix the bad code. However this coworker has actually left the company and the only notes say that it's a bad cast, and I'm trying to figure out some more details about why because I'm curious.

Comment: Casts that involve pointers are usually signs of bad (i.e. invalid) code.

Comment: @StoryTeller done, also I added some extra context about what the function is purporting to do.

Comment: _I don't really know much C++_ don’t worry, your coworker didn’t either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike the widespread and erroneously taught belief, arrays are **not** pointers. They may *decay* into pointers in most contexts, but the address-of operator is not one of those contexts.

If the type of `z_strings` is `char[3]`, then the type of `&z_strings` is `char (*)[3]`. It is a pointer to an array of three characters. And a pointer to an array is not compatible with a pointer to a pointer.

That's what's wrong with your cast. As for how to fix it, with the little context you've shown, the obvious solution is to introduce an actual pointer:

```
char *p_z_strings = z_strings; //decay here
MyFunction(myints, &p_z_strings , another_int_arg); // no cast; exact match
```

---

With the *added* context you provided, the "obvious" solution is now rather glaringly incorrect. There's still a few details missing, but if we are working under the assumption that `GetPowers` will do the allocation for the new strings, we do not need additional variables:

```
char* z_strings[3]; // Now we have an array of pointers
GetPowers(p_int, z_strings, 3); // It decays into a pointer to a pointer
// GetPowers populates it
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.

Comment: To check my understanding for your new solution, is the problem that `char z_strings[3]` can't actually hold multiple strings (it would just be a string allocated with 3 bytes) and thus we need to upgrade it to `char* z_strings[3]` where each entry is actually a pointer to a string? (By string I technically mean array of chars)

Comment: @Stephen - Your understanding is correct so far. `GetPowers` wants to access a buffer of pointers. So that's what we provide.

Answer (score 1):

The cast is bad, because it shuts up the compiler, without fixing the code.

The real fix might be using the proper array, which could be (as the function argument type suggests) an array of pointers, e.g.

```
char *z_strings[3];
```

Now you can call the function without any cast at all:

```
MyFunction(myints, z_strings, another_int_arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ an array 'decays' to a pointer when the identifier is used as an argument to a function that expects a pointer. This means that if you have a function that takes a `char*` (C and common C++ form of a string argument) then you can just pass it a `char` array and no casting is required.

In your example, you are casting to a `char**` which is a pointer to a pointer to a char. This suggests the function expects to change what a `char*` argument points to and this is not something that makes sense with an array argument. Without knowing more context here it's hard to give a more specific answer to your question though. It's also possible that a `char**` argument could be intended to be an array of strings (in which case you would expect an additional array size argument) but without seeing what `MyFunction()` is intended to do it's hard to say.